# Antivirus scan for uploading files

Tags: php, file-upload, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I have a Webapp where user can upload documents(pdf, doc, rtf, txt etc) and want to check for virus before them getting uploaded. I am running this server on centos instance and using PHP for the webapp.

What Anti virus do you think are best for this kind of functionality. I am fine with any paid solution also, but it should have latest database for virus and can scan efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a list on antivirus software for ubuntu, and they should be [LSD compatible](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb), so they should work on Centos. You can use the link above the check if they are.

The list is **[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)**, and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Anti-virus_applications) also contains a list of linux antiviruses.

I am not sure if they all suit your needs, but I know that AVIRA has a [command line scanner](http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-command-line-scanner-scancl).

Here are some sample lines of code:

```
scancl / --defaultaction=ask
scancl /var/www -z --defaultaction=repair,delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the antivirus program itself to live on your centos OS, or are you open to connecting to the antivirus solution running on another server (or hosted solution)?